# Cannot print class objects

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to learn OOP and got some exercise to do with strings, but when I try to print the objects, I get an error:
line 27, in 
rezultatas = laboras(pradine, abecele, nepasikartojantys, pasikartojantys)
NameError: name 'pradine' is not defined

My code:

```
import collections
class laboras:

    def __init__(self,pradine,abecele,nepasikartojantys,pasikartojantys):
        self.pradine = pradine
        self.abecele = abecele
        self.nepasikartojantys = nepasikartojantys
        self.pasikartojantys = pasikartojantys
    #pradine
    pradine = input('Iveskite bent 10 tarpais atskirtu zodziu seka: ')
    #abecele
    s = sorted(pradine.split(), key=str.lower)
    abecele = ' '.join(map(str,s))
    #nepasikartojantys
    nepasikartoja = list(dict.fromkeys(abecele.split()))
    nepasikartojantys = ' '.join(map(str,nepasikartoja))
    #pasikartojantys
    pradine1 = pradine.split()
    pasikartojantys = collections.Counter(pradine1)

    def spausdinimas(self):
        print(self.pradine)
        print(self.abecele)
        print(self.nepasikartojantys)
        print(self.pasikartojantys)

rezultatas = laboras(pradine, abecele, nepasikartojantys, pasikartojantys)
rezultatas.spausdinimas()
```

Comment: Looks like all of that code in the body of the class definition (everything outside of the definitions of `.__init__()` and `.spausdinimas()`) needs to be moved entirely outside of the class, and unindented.

Comment: Due to its indentation under the class declaration, ou're executing `pradine = input('Iveskite bent 10 tarpais atskirtu zodziu seka: ')` *during the definition* of the class `laboras`, in that class's scope. `pradine` subsequently becomes an attribute of the class: `laboras.pradine`. I am pretty sure that's not what you want, so do what @jasonharper says.

Comment: Also, your question asks about printing the object, but your problem has nothing to do with printing. It doesn't get that far.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by amending my code to this:

```
import collections
class laboras:

    def __init__(self,pradine,abecele,nepasikartojantys,pasikartojantys):
        self.pradine = pradine
        self.abecele = abecele
        self.nepasikartojantys = nepasikartojantys
        self.pasikartojantys = pasikartojantys

    def spausdinimas(self):
        print(self.pradine)
        print(self.abecele)
        print(self.nepasikartojantys)
        print(self.pasikartojantys)
#pradine
pradine = input('Iveskite bent 10 tarpais atskirtu zodziu seka: ')
#abecele
s = sorted(pradine.split(), key=str.lower)
abecele = ' '.join(map(str,s))
#nepasikartojantys
nepasikartoja = list(dict.fromkeys(abecele.split()))
nepasikartojantys = ' '.join(map(str,nepasikartoja))
#pasikartojantys
pradine1 = pradine.split()
pasikartojantys = collections.Counter(pradine1)

rezultatas = laboras(pradine, abecele, nepasikartojantys, pasikartojantys)
rezultatas.spausdinimas()
```

What I've done is just moved all the code out from the class except spausdinimas() function.